# Can not dvc push to a NAS

Tags: nas, dvc

I am trying to use DVC with a remote set to a NAS. So I did

```
dvc remote add -d myremote1 https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/
```

but after this I cannot push.

I tried

```
dvc remote modify --local myremote1 user justme
dvc remote modify --local myremote1 password mysupersecretpassword
```

but after this

```
dvc push

Collecting                                                                                                               |0.00 [00:00,    ?entry/s]
ERROR: failed to transfer '22a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f' - 401, message='Unauthorized', url=URL(https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5/22/a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f')                                                                                  
Pushing                                                                                                                                            
ERROR: failed to push data to the cloud - 1 files failed to upload
```

I also tried

```
dvc remote modify myremote1 auth basic
```

and later I erased my password and set

```
dvc remote modify  myremote1 ask_password true
```

with this I got

```
dvc push
Enter a password for host 'None' user 'justme':                       

Collecting                                                                                                               |0.00 [00:00,    ?entry/s]
ERROR: failed to transfer '22a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f' - https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5/22/a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f                                                                                                                          
Pushing                                                                                                                                            
ERROR: failed to push data to the cloud - 1 files failed to upload
```

Something that calls my attention: Why does it say "Enter a password for host 'None'???

Host None?

What can I do to succesfuly setup a remote and push data to it?

EDIT:

DVC version: 3.39.0

```
dvc push -v
2024-01-17 13:58:53,722 DEBUG: v3.39.0 (pip), CPython 3.9.16 on Linux-5.15.0-91-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
2024-01-17 13:58:53,722 DEBUG: command: /home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/bin/dvc push -v
Enter a password for host 'None' user 'justme':                       

Collecting                                                                                                               |0.00 [00:00,    ?entry/s]
2024-01-17 13:59:05,556 DEBUG: Preparing to transfer data from '/path/to/example1/.dvc/cache/files/md5' to 'https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5'
2024-01-17 13:59:05,556 DEBUG: Preparing to collect status from 'https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5'
2024-01-17 13:59:05,557 DEBUG: Collecting status from 'https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5'
2024-01-17 13:59:05,559 DEBUG: Querying 1 oids via object_exists
2024-01-17 13:59:05,621 DEBUG: Preparing to collect status from '/path/to/example1/.dvc/cache/files/md5'                          
2024-01-17 13:59:05,621 DEBUG: Collecting status from '/path/to/example1/.dvc/cache/files/md5'                                    
2024-01-17 13:59:05,776 ERROR: failed to transfer '22a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f' - https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5/22/a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/generic.py", line 330, in transfer
    _try_links(
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/generic.py", line 262, in _try_links
    return copy(
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/generic.py", line 87, in copy
    return _put(
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/generic.py", line 156, in _put
    return _put_one(from_paths[0], to_paths[0])
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/generic.py", line 148, in _put_one
    return put_file(from_path, to_path, callback=callback, **put_file_kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/callbacks.py", line 146, in sync_wrapper
    res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/callbacks.py", line 164, in sync_wrapper
    return fn(path1, path2, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_objects/fs/base.py", line 643, in put_file
    self.fs.put_file(os.fspath(from_file), to_info, callback=callback, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 103, in sync
    raise return_result
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 56, in _runner
    result[0] = await coro
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc_http/spec.py", line 11, in _put_file
    return await super()._put_file(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/implementations/http.py", line 311, in _put_file
    self._raise_not_found_for_status(resp, rpath)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/implementations/http.py", line 216, in _raise_not_found_for_status
    raise FileNotFoundError(url)
FileNotFoundError: https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5/22/a1a2931c8370d3aeedd7183606fd7f

Pushing
2024-01-17 13:59:05,780 ERROR: failed to push data to the cloud - 1 files failed to upload                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/commands/data_sync.py", line 64, in run
    processed_files_count = self.repo.push(
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/repo/__init__.py", line 65, in wrapper
    return f(repo, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dvc/repo/push.py", line 171, in push
    raise UploadError(failed_count)
dvc.exceptions.UploadError: 1 files failed to upload

2024-01-17 13:59:05,783 DEBUG: Analytics is enabled.
2024-01-17 13:59:05,838 DEBUG: Trying to spawn ['daemon', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp32qevoi2', '-v']
2024-01-17 13:59:05,844 DEBUG: Spawned ['daemon', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp32qevoi2', '-v'] with pid 3223147
```

EDIT2:
**An even stranger thing happened!**: I could push!

But no contents were pushed.

I deleted manually the port from the remote address
(so now it is `https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/`)

and I did

```
>dvc push -v
2024-01-23 19:08:22,593 DEBUG: v3.39.0 (pip), CPython 3.9.16 on Linux-5.15.0-91-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
2024-01-23 19:08:22,593 DEBUG: command: /home/justme/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/example1-ui6lFrCK-py3.9/bin/dvc push -v
Enter a password for host 'None' user 'justme':                       

Collecting                                                                                                             |0.00 [00:00,    ?entry/s]
2024-01-23 19:08:34,697 DEBUG: Preparing to transfer data from 
/path/to/example1/.dvc/cache/files/md5' to 'https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5'
2024-01-23 19:08:34,697 DEBUG: Preparing to collect status from 'https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5'
2024-01-23 19:08:34,697 DEBUG: Collecting status from 'https://mynas.url.something.es:3444/thefolder/dvcstore1/files/md5'
2024-01-23 19:08:34,699 DEBUG: Querying 1 oids via object_exists
Pushing                                                                                                                                          
Everything is up to date.                                                                                                                        
2024-01-23 19:08:35,188 DEBUG: Analytics is enabled.
2024-01-23 19:08:35,264 DEBUG: Trying to spawn ['daemon', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp82uf158p', '-v']
2024-01-23 19:08:35,270 DEBUG: Spawned ['daemon', 'analytics', '/tmp/tmp82uf158p', '-v'] with pid 2311402
```

However nothing is in the remote address

Comment: Could you please include some logs? Run it with `-v`. To see what is happening there. Thanks.

Comment: Also `dvc version` output would be helpful.

Comment: @Shcheklein I added the info.

Comment: do you see any files created on the NAS? any directories? Specifically, there should be at least `files/md5/22`

Comment: @Shcheklein no, the transfer failed so there is nothing there

Comment: I think server should be setup (if you don't decide to mount it of course) in a way that when a request like PUT / POST "files/md5/22/file_name" it creates a directory for the file. My guess would be that it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Shcheklein Thanks. Any clue on why it says "Enter a password for host 'None'"<--this?

Answer (score 0):

It is typical to mount the NAS and then push to that mounted drive (see https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/data-management/remote-storage#file-systems-local-remotes). It's not common to transfer via http, so you may want to try mounting the NAS first unless you are sure that your NAS supports transferring directly over http and you have a strong reason to prefer this method.

Comment: ohhhh I see. I have mounted the NAS in the past, so with that the dvc remote will be like doing it with a local directory.....

Comment: How can I make sure -just in case- that the NAS supports or not htto transferring?